# is the UDP or TCP protocol best for sending back un-noticed packets / datagrams

Tags: networking, tcp, udp, port-scanning

so I'm working on a project where the program can detect when its being scanned for malicious purposes by checking how many ports are being scanned at the same time and scanning them back using the SYN method and I would like to know if the TCP or UDP protocol is better for a so called "counter-scan" to the target without getting noticed I have some ideas like:

1. I can send them using UDP and the attacker wouldn't notice them .
2. using the TCP method use the existing 3 way handshake to mask the
   SYN packets with his responses

sorry I have no source code since I'm still brain storming

Comment: UDP is explicitly connectionless, and it does not have a SYN, which is used by TCP to synchronize a connection (hence SYN for synchronize). Scanning back does nothing to discourage the behavior, and it lets the other side know you are there and may have something worth attacking. It just is not a smart move. You should ask about this on [security.se].

Comment: i just realized it didn't but i will use the feedback that the server will return to see if the host is open or not using the IMCP response and i plan to do it as stealthily as possible so this doesn't happen

Answer (score 0):

Yes, UDP scan can be done by looking at ICMP (NOT IMCP) port unreachables, but these are often filtered.

I guess UDP would not be less "noticed"--TCP does more harm since it needs state saved (waiting for ACKs).

(nit:  please work on your English)